How can you create a signin in Azure B2C custom policies with type of document, number of document and password?
I'm trying to add the display claims to the technical profile SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email but but then it does somehting strange with the layout. It only shows two filds: the type of document and another one that look like combination of the number of document and the password. (I don't really know what I'm doing)
enter image description here
<ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="documentType">
        <DisplayName>Document Type</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText />
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$"
            HelpText="..." />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="documentNumber">
        <DisplayName>Document Number</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText />
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
            <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$" HelpText="..." />
        </Restriction>
    </ClaimType>
</ClaimsSchema>


<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
    <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="documentType" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="documentNumber" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="documentType" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="documentNumber" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
        </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>


The issue you're experiencing may be due to how the claims are being displayed or how they're mapped within the DisplayClaims section. The layout is affected when claims like documentType and documentNumber are not separated properly in the UI. Try to adjust the UI by ensuring each claim has a corresponding display control, such as a label or input box. Also, make sure that the regular expression pattern is correct, as it can cause issues in rendering the claims correctly.

Thank you @Rukmini. How can I do that? With DisplayControl tag?
